# How to create a file not a directory automatically when mount a host file from container

Tags: docker

I'm writing a cli which will generate a markdown file when finished, and I build a docker image for that cli.

I want to mount the markdown file generated by the container to host machine.

docker -v will create a folder not a file automatically when the path not exist on host.

For example.
 ~/result.md not exist at first.

```
docker run -it --rm -v ~/result.md:/usr/src/work_dir/result.md cli:latest generate_markdown
```

After running, `~/result.md` folder is created but not file, and the cli throw an exception because of write to a directory not a file.

To avoid this, I have to create a file at first, and run the docker cli subsequently. It works fine.
Is it possible to avoid create the file at the beginning ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try -

```
$docker volume create myvol

$docker run -it --rm -v myvol:/usr/src/work_dir/ cli:latest generate_markdown
```

Alternately, you can just

`$docker run -it --rm -v myvol:/usr/src/work_dir/ cli:latest generate_markdown`

Want an explanation ?

You are using a bind mount; in your case

`docker run -it --rm -v ~/result.md:/usr/src/work_dir/result.md cli:latest generate_markdown`

The solution to your problem might just be a **volume mount**.
For more info refer - https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

First **create a docker volume** by-
`$docker volume create myvol`
. You can give any name instead of myvol.

This docker volume will be created, you can **check if the volume was created successfully** by-

`$docker volume ls`
This will give a list of your all your volumes, your newly created volume should be listed.

```
ak@ubuntu:~$ docker volume create myvol
myvol
ak@ubuntu:~$ docker volume ls
DRIVER              VOLUME NAME
local               myvol
```

*Docker Volumes are stored in a separate area on the host file system and are completely managed by docker as opposed to bind mounts.Docker volumes store state outside of containers, so your data survives when you replace the container to update your app.*

Docker volumes also get automatically created in case you specify  a name instead of a directory path. In the following example a volume by the name myvol2 will be automatically created -

`$docker run -it -v myvol2:/home/myfiles imagename:tag`

Docker volumes are usually created in `/var/lib/docker/volumes`
in linux and in `C:\ProgramData\docker\volumes` in Windows.

**Now here's the useful part**. Any data/file/directories that already exist in the specified container directory are automatically copied or 'mounted' onto the docker volume. Therefore if the '''/usr/src/work_dir/''' directory mentioned in the above example contains any files (like a markup file in your case), they are copied onto the volume automatically.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The volume mount will assume a directory name passed in, not a file. You can either mount the volume `~` or have a directory created and mount that volume.

```sh
mkdir ~/markdown
docker run -it --rm -v ~/markdown/:/usr/src/work_dir/ cli:latest generate_markdown
```

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid mounting files all together accordijg to best practices. That being said it is not possible to change the x fault behaviour that you describe.

The solution to you problem (to not create the file each time before running the container) is to mount the directories, omitting the file names.

```
docker run -it --rm -v ~/:/usr/src/work_dir/ cli:latest generate_markdown
```